# AngularJS - ui-date replace with HTML 5 Date Picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I was having `angularjs ui-date` in my page. Now i have replaced it with HTML5 Date Picker.

The value i used to get when having `angularjs ui-date` was like this :-

`Fri May 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

When i use HTML 5 Date Picker, I get value like this :-

`2014-05-02`

Due to this my Search functionality fails.

How to convert this value to match like `ui-date` with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The html datepicker uses yyy-mm-dd format, and as far as i can see, you can't change that. The thing you can do is with javascript, convert it to the format you'd like in a hidden field, and use that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library to convert the date into the format you want like :

```
moment(date).format('yyyy-MM-DD');
```